# How can I limit the output of a CakePHP query?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to learn CakePHP, and attempting to replicate what I can do with standard PHP and MySQL with Cake.

I have an `event` table with event information, and an `list_items` table that holds entries for a bullet pointed list to be displayed on each event page. The `list_items` table consists of 3 columns: `id`,`event_id`,`listinfo`. The latter is the string to be displayed.

I have associated the two tables:

```
class Event extends AppModel{

    public $hasMany = array(
        'ListItem'
        );

}
```

and:

```
class ListItem extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Event'
    );

}
```

and the Event controller has the query to find an event based on the ID:

```
public function view($id = null){
if (!$id){
throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Course'));
}

$event = $this->Event->findById($id);
if (!$event){
throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid event'));
}
$this->set('event',$event);

}
```

I have my view set up:

```
  <?php 

    foreach($event['ListItem'] as $listItem):
       echo $this->Html->nestedList($listItem);
    endforeach; ?>
```

My problem is, this outputs *everything* in `list_items`:

```
1
1
This is list item 1
2
1
This is list item 2
```

e.g. the keys *and* the actual string.

How can I limit the output to just the string? I am a bit confused by the way associations (heck, and MVC in general) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html::nestedList()` is used for associative arrays, not indexed.

The [example cake gives](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3anestedList) shows when you would use it.

For your case, you would do this:

```
foreach($event['ListItem'] as $listItem):
   echo 'ListItem ID: ' . $listItem['id'] . ' is ' . $listItem['listinfo'] . 
        ' and belongs to Event:' . $listItem['event_id'];
endforeach;
```

If you do `debug($event);` somewhere in your view, you will see exactly what the data looks like and may help you visualise the associations better.